# moment format using i18n

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am replacing moment by date-fns and I found this code, that I do not understand the moment part (what moment does). I understand the map function.

```js
this.events[0].dates.map(date => moment(date).format(this.$i18n.locale))
```

I create an environment to test the moment function, but the result I got was weird and now I am completely lost.

I passed to

```
moment()

const startDate = "2021-07-26";
const actualDay = new Date();
const timeStamp = 1624988893000;
```

to figure out what this function does, and all time the result was something like this **MOMENT TEST 610-63**

I think there is something wrong with that function, but I am doubting, maybe too much.

Comment: Moment's [documentation of the `format` function](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is pretty good, and shows what the string should be. If I'm not mistaken `$i18n.locale` contains a BCP47 locale string (like "en-US" for English United States), which is not a valid format string, which would explain the odd results you're getting. The [Moment documentation has a section on i18n](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) that you probably want to read.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the documentation and  this it seems not correct **moment(date).format(this.$i18n.locale)** what I understood. I have to use moment().locale(this.$i18n.locale).format() and not moment().format( $i18n.locale) directly.

Comment: Maybe My question is not enough clear. I should add I am replacing moment by date-fns and I wanted to be sure to get the same result as this moment function. But I found the result weird, I think it is because the code has an issue and it is not possible pass this.i18n.local directly to the format method insted It has to be used locale() and after that, format with the corresponding token

Answer (score 0):

What momentjs is doing is clearly described here:

https://momentjs.com/

moment is awaiting a date. So

```
moment(new Date()).format()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/95dbLmkf/

Is giving you current date and time in ISO format.

I do not know what i18n.locale contains but I guess it is not a valid date format string as required by momentjs format command.

Maybe you just console.log the value of i18n.locale to see what it is passing through the format function.

Comment: A link to jsfiddle.net without linking to a specific fiddle is hardly illustrative of anything.  If you don't know what `i18n.locale` contains, ask, using a comment, then answer when you know. Answers like this are rarely helpful in explaining what is going on.

Comment: Thanks claus. I know moment could be used like this moment() or moment(string, object, number),format(). format Should has a valid token and this.i18n.locale is not valid. 

I just wanted to be sure I was not doiing stuff bad. It is my first task as frontend and as well my first job jejjee. 

Thanks.

Comment: And I like people who complain about downvotes "without any reason" but also complain when given a reason. My comment did help as it got you to look at the link again and provide a link to a specific fiddle. It also informs you of the requirements of a good answer; one that is informed. See [answer] for more tips on writing good answers that will stand the test of time.